# How to pass data between components Laravel

Tags: laravel, attributes, components, laravel-blade

Hello I'm confused on how should I pass collections/data to another component so I can display it in another component (in this case I'm showing discounts so it will be a section with popular discounts and another section showing latest discounts).

So i have this `index.blade.php` and i'm a bit confused on how to pass the data to `x-discount-card` component so I can access to `$discount->title` on the component. Right now I get "undefined variable $discount" so it seems i'm not accessing it right.

```
<x-layout>
    <main>
        @include('components.categories-row')
        @include('discounts._best')
        <section class="w-4/6 mx-auto my-8 font-bold flex flex-col items-center justify-center">
            <h1 class="uppercase text-main-gray text-4xl bold self-start text-center mb-4 ">Últimos Descuentos</h1>
            @if($discounts->count())
                @foreach($discounts as $discount)
                    <x-discount-card :discount="$discount" />
                @endforeach

            @else
                <p class="my-8 text-center">No hay descuentos disponibles. Por favor vuelva mas tarde. </p>
            @endif
        </section>
    </main>
</x-layout>
```

discount-component

```
@props(['discount'])

<div
    class="w-[20rem] h-auto bg-gradient-to-b from-card-light-gray to-card-main-gray p-6 rounded-2xl drop-shadow-xl md:w-[35rem] lg:w-[35rem] lg:w-[50rem] lg:h-auto mb-4">
    <div class="flex-col items-center text-center justify-center h-full lg:grid lg:grid-cols-4 lg:grid-rows-4">
        <a href="" class="flex justify-center lg:row-span-4 lg:-ml-10">
            <img class="h-full " src="/images/pngwing.com.png" alt="" width="120" height="120">
        </a>
        <div
            class="flex-col justify-center items-center text-center w-full  lg:col-start-2 lg:col-span-full lg:row-start-1 lg:row-span-full lg:-ml-14">
            <a href="/discount/1" class="lg:grid lg:row-start-2">
                <h2 class="text-white font-bold text-lg md:text-2xl lg:my-2">{{ $discount->title }}</h2>
                <div class="flex my-4 items-center text-center justify-center lg:my-2">
                    <p class="text-price-color font-bold mr-8 text-xl md:text-2xl">139,99€</p>
                    <p class="line-through text-white text-lg md:text-lg">149,99 (-10€)</p>
                </div>
                <p class="text-white my-8 text-sm md:text-lg lg:my-4">Bambas nike con 10€ de descuento y envio gratis.
                    Salen a
                    139,99€</p>
            </a>
            <div
                class="flex-col items-center justify-center gap-2 lg:flex-row lg:inline-flex lg:col-start-2 lg:col-span-full lg:row-start-4 lg:row-end-5">
                <a class="flex items-center justify-center my-2 " href="/user/1">
                    <img class="rounded-full mr-2" src="https://i.pravatar.cc/35"
                         alt="">
                    <p class="mr-4 text-white text-sm font-bold transition-transform hover:translate-x-0.5 md:text-lg">
                        JohnDoe</p>
                </a>
                <div class="flex items-center justify-center my-4 gap-4 lg:mx-4">
                    <div
                        class="border border-light-gray p-1 rounded-md transition-transform hover:-translate-y-0.5 cursor-pointer">
                        <img class="h-full" src="/images/heart.png" alt="" width="22" height="22">
                    </div>
                    <div
                        class="border border-light-gray p-1 rounded-md transition-transform hover:-translate-y-0.5 cursor-pointer">
                        <img class="h-full" src="/images/dislike.png" alt="" width="22" height="22">
                    </div>
                    <div
                        class="flex items-center border border-light-gray p-1 rounded-md transition-transform hover:-translate-y-0.5 cursor-pointer lg:px-4">
                        <img class="h-full" src="/images/comment.png" alt="" width="22" height="22">
                        <p class="text-light-gray ml-2">10</p>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="flex justify-center lg:w-[250px] lg:-mr-14">
                    <button
                        class="flex my-4 items-center justify-center bg-gradient-to-b from-button-light-orange to-button-dark-orange p-2 rounded-md transition-transform hover:-translate-y-0.5 md:p-4 lg:w-full ">
                        <p class="text-light-gray mr-4 font-bold text-sm md:text-lg ">Ver Chollo</p>
                        <img src="/images/external-link.png" alt="" width="20" height="20">
                    </button>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div
        class="w-auto absolute top-5 left-5 flex-col items-center justify-center rounded-2xl bg-button-light-orange p-2 drop-shadow-lg md:flex-row md:inline-flex">
        <p class="text-white text-xs uppercase font-bold mr-2 md:text-sm ">10%</p>
        <p class="text-white text-xs uppercase font-bold md:text-sm ">descuento</p>
    </div>

</div>
```

Also on the `routes` file i'm passing discounts but i'm a bit confused on how should I pass the data because right now i'm getting "undefined variable $discount error"

```
Route::get('/', function () {
    return view('discounts.index', [
        'discounts' => Discount::all(),
//            ->where('premium','=',false)
        'categories' => Category::all()
    ]);
})->name('home');
```

On the `discounts._best` component i'll display the discounts with more likes but this will be done in the future but I share the component too because maybe something there is what is causing the error.

```
    <section class=" w-full text-center h-3/4 bg-light-gray flex flex-col items-center justify-center p-10">
        <h1 class="uppercase text-main-gray mb-8 text-4xl font-bold">Descuentos Populares</h1>
        <x-discount-card  />
    </section>
```

I searched on the Laravel Documentation about Component attributes but I dont know what i'm doing wrong and still confused.

Comment: you can either comment out `<x-discount-card />` in `discounts._best` view or assign a default value to prop `discount` in the <x-discount-card>` component or pass a `discount` to the `<x-discount-card :discount="$bestDiscount" /> `in `discounts._best` view, where for the time being `$bestDiscount` could be a dummy data. If you do not have default value for `@props` in blade component, then a value must be passed as prop in the markup, else it will throw `undefined` error for the prop variables

Comment: Ok thanks for this, managed to solve it. It seems that the discount card on ._best was the problema. I guess it will be a better idea to make a separate component for the best discount card or it will be ok to use <x-discount-card :discount="$bestDiscount" /> as you said?